Issue with string length validation in assembly and C
I'm new to assembly language and I'm working on a program that combines assembly language with parts written in C. My goal is to prompt the user to input a string of characters and ensure that it does not exceed 50 characters. However, I'm experiencing an issue with the validation of the string length.
Here's my code:
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {
    char str[51];  // Allow for 50 characters + null terminator
    char temp[101]; // Temporary buffer to detect overflow

    // Prompt user for input
    printf("Enter a string (max 50 characters): ");
    fgets(temp, sizeof(temp), stdin);

    // Remove newline character if present
    temp[strcspn(temp, "\n")] = '\0';

    // Validate string length
    int length = strlen(temp);
    if (length > 50) {
        printf("String exceeds 50 characters.\n");
        return 1;
    }

    // Copy the validated string to the main buffer
    strcpy(str, temp);

    // Inline assembly to reverse the string
    __asm__ (
        "mov %[len], %%esi\n\t"     // esi = length
        "decl %%esi\n\t"            // esi = length - 1 (last character index)
        "xor %%ecx, %%ecx\n\t"      // ecx = 0 (starting index)

        "reverse_loop:\n\t"
        "cmp %%esi, %%ecx\n\t"      // Compare start and end indexes
        "jge loop_end\n\t"          // If start >= end, end loop

        "movb (%[str], %%ecx), %%al\n\t"  // al = str[ecx]
        "movb (%[str], %%esi), %%bl\n\t"  // bl = str[esi]

        "movb %%bl, (%[str], %%ecx)\n\t"  // str[ecx] = bl
        "movb %%al, (%[str], %%esi)\n\t"  // str[esi] = al

        "incl %%ecx\n\t"            // Increment start index
        "decl %%esi\n\t"            // Decrement end index
        "jmp reverse_loop\n\t"      // Repeat loop

        "loop_end:\n\t"
        :
        : [str] "r" (str), [len] "r" (length)
        : "%esi", "%ecx", "%al", "%bl"
    );

    // Print the reversed string
    printf("Reversed string: %s\n", str);

    return 0;
}


The issue I'm encountering is that the program incorrectly reports that the entered string exceeds 50 characters, despite the input string actually containing fewer than 50 characters. Attached is a screenshot demonstrating this problem.

Note: The command utilized was: gcc -Wall -g string.c -o string
I have reviewed my code and considered that the issue might be related to how I'm removing the newline character and how I'm counting the length of the string. However, I haven't been able to pinpoint the exact cause of the problem.
I would greatly appreciate any suggestions or guidance on how I can troubleshoot and resolve this issue to ensure that the string length validation works correctly. Thank you for your help!

I counted about 60. 60 > 50. Seems right to me. Did one or both of us miscount?

Also do not post pictures of text. Would be easier to copy-paste and count it.

Why have temp be 101 but str be only 51? This limitation seems artificial and counter to the main goal of writing the reverse function in asm. Make them both the same and how about 10000 for each? Why have two buffers at all? Just read into one buffer and operate on it directly.

Since you're doing fgets on a buffer reading from stdin it will always terminate the buffer with 0. If the string is too large, it will elide the newline. Instead of using strcspn, try: char *nl = strchr(buf,'\n'); if (nl != NULL) *nl = 0; else printf("line too long\n");

Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?

the first string is already exactly 50 characters long. So obviously the longer one has length > 50

Do not post images/links of code. Images are often chopped, leave out necessary info, can't be downloaded. Use code block(s).  To create a code block: In your editor/IDE/gdb, select the [desired] text. Copy to clipboard [with ctrl-c]. Edit the question here [using the edit button]. Scroll to bottom. Enter \``on a separate line [to start a code block]. Thenctrl-vto paste in the text. Then, another```` line [to end the code block]. Then, click on the save button. You already did this for your code. You can do from the window you posted an image of.

To restrict the input to your max (50) bytes
either replace
fgets(temp, sizeof(temp), stdin);
with
fgets(temp, sizeof(str)-1, stdin);
or leave as is and remove the length test
    int length = strlen(temp);
    if (length > 50) {
        printf("String exceeds 50 characters.\n");
        return 1;
    }

perhaps with a notification (example ...)
 if( strlen(temp) > sizeof(str)-1 )
   printf("String is %lu length, only %lu will be taken.\n", strlen(temp), sizeof(str)-1 );

finally, replace
strcpy(str, temp);
with
strncpy(str, temp, sizeof(str)-1 );
to guarantee that str cannot be overflowed
